# python solution for browser automation

Tags: python, macos, selenium, browser

I'm learning python with videos I download through sites like clipconverter so I can study while traveling on a boat offline. I want to automate the downloading as i select links from youtube search results. Manually i copy the link address into my mac scratchpad,  open the download site, paste the url, selecting format options then press a sequence of buttons with pauses. I don't think there is a free service with an api so I looked at Selenium IDE but did not find it flexible enough for me to point to any link then execute the recording. I see python can control selenium but don't want to head down that road if I can fashion a pure python solution that would be more instructive to me. I see python libraries to control the browser so i'm hoping to make this my first python application but seem stuck without very specific examples so am looking for an approach to guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should take a look into existing solutions written in python: like [youtube-dl](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#readme). You could download multiple videos by creating multiple threads that call the script or instead just use their set of extensive options.

However keep in mind that downloading Youtube videos is against their Terms of Service.

Answer (score 0):

On Github you can find many programs that do that. Beware that this is against the Youtube Terms of Service, but you can get videos legally from sites like [coursera](https://www.coursera.org/courses?query=python) and [pythonspot](https://pythonspot.com/videos/)